# Seeking PostGIS equivalent of Geopandas dissolve method

Tags: postgis, dissolve, aggregation

Suppose I have a multiline string feature that I have brought into PostgreSQL as a table called `nld_table` with the following columns: 'SystemID', 'SystemName', 'Location', 'Accred', 'NLD_Access', 'geom'. Previously, I was using a Python script that read the line features into a geodataframe called 'nld_gdf' using geopandas. This Python script would then use the `geopandas.dissolve()` method to aggregate based on non-geometry columns like this:

```
  systems_dissolve = nld_gdf.dissolve(by='SystemID', aggfunc='first', as_index=False)
```

I want to replicate this logic using PostGIS. I am looking at `ST_Union()`, `ST_Collect()`, or `ST_LineMerge()` but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I want. I want to do the following: Dissolve/Union/Merge the geometry based on the first instance of 'SystemID'.

```
 SELECT 'SystemID', 
    'SystemName', 
    'Location', 
    'Accred', 
    'NLD_Access', 
    ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(geom))) AS geom
 FROM myschema.nld_table
 GROUP BY 'SystemID'
 ORDER BY 'SystemID'
```

This doesn't seem to be quite correct.

How do I achieve what I want here?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: You can try `ST_LineMerge(ST_Node(ST_Collect(geom)))` - `ST_Node` is a linework specific implementation of an *unary union*. Merging lines based on 2-way intersections via `ST_LineMerge` is a bonus - not sure if GeoPandas `dissolve` includes that step.